# Pythonic way for returning elements of one list by an order-preserved comparation of two other lists

Tags: python, list, compare

I have three lists: `vals1`, `vals2`, and `names`. `names` includes only strings and the other two lists (`vals1`, `vals2`) contain numbers only. The lengths of the three lists are always the same. My goal is to write a function that compares `vals1`and `vals2` and return a message or a list depending on the result of the comparison. If `vals1`and `vals2` are equal, then the function returns a message that states the two lists are equal. List comparison must be done in the preserved order. For example, `vals1 = [1,2,3,2]` is not equal to `vals2 = [1,2,2,3]`. If the two numeric lists (`vals1`and `vals2`) are not equal, the function will return a list that contains tuples. Each tuple in this list contains the index of one element in `vals1` and `vals2` that are not equal, the corresponding element in the string list `names`, and the corresponding element in `vals1`. This is the function that I wrote for this task:

```
def compareLists(l1, l2, names):
    if l1==l2:
        return "Equal"
    else:
        return ([(item, idx, val) for (item, idx, val) in 
               zip(names, range(len(names)), l1) if l1[idx]!=l2[idx]])
```

For

```
vals1=[12, 2, 2, 7, 5]
vals2=[12, 5, 2, 7, 15]
names=['a','b','c','d','e']
```

`compareLists` will return

```
[('b', 1, 2), ('e', 4, 5)]
```

The function works, but I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way (a more pythonic approach) to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your method, imo.

Alternatively, you could use `zip` + `enumerate`:

```
out = [(n, idx, i) for idx, (i, j, n) in enumerate(zip(vals1, vals2, names)) if i!=j]
out = out if out else 'equal'
```

If you have Python >=3.8, you can also write the above in one line (a lot less readable though):

```
out = out if (out:= [(n, idx, i) for idx, (i, j, n) in enumerate(zip(vals1, vals2, names)) if i!=j]) else 'equal'
```

Output:

```
[('b', 1, 2), ('e', 4, 5)]
```

We could also write a genexp (thanks @JonClements):

```
t = ((n, idx, i) for idx, (i, j, n) in enumerate(zip(vals1, vals2, names)) if i!=j)
out = 'equal' if vals1 == vals2 else list(t)
```

Comment: Could also turn `t` into a gen-exp: `((n, idx, i) for idx, (i, j, n) in enumerate(zip(vals1, vals2, names)) if i!=j)` to avoid precomputing the list if not needed and then the return becomes `return 'equal' if l1 == l2 else list(t)` - but that's not massively different that what the OP is doing... the main difference here is that `enumerate` is just cleaner than iterating over `range(len(...))`

Comment: @JonClements that's an excellent idea, I'll put it in; thanks!

Comment: That last one is the winner in my book :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `enumerate()` as opposed to using `range()`. You can also remove the `else` in the function, as it's redundant:

```py
def compareLists(l1, l2, names):
    if l1 == l2:
        return "Equal"
    return ([(item, idx, val) for idx, (item, val) in 
               enumerate(zip(names, l1)) if l1[idx] != l2[idx]])

vals1=[12, 2, 2, 7, 5]
vals2=[12, 5, 2, 7, 15]
names=['a','b','c','d','e']
print(compareLists(vals1, vals2, names))
```